# Да потому(,) что - нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Ответ тривиален: "Да потому(,) что им значительно проще это дается".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, опционально. 
Союз "потому что" может оформляться двояко. Либо с запятой перед "что", либо перед "потому". обычно -  в зависимости от интонации. 
***Светло потому, что Солнце светит.*** - акцент на "потому".
***Светло, потому что Солнце светит.*** - акцент на "что".

Но в начале фразы обычен только второй вариант, с акцентом на "что". Запятой, понятно, не требуется. Но если считать "да" усилительной частицей, то акцент вполне может смещаться на "потому", даже скорее всего смещается.
Короче, думаю, можно и так и так.

Comment: Светло, потому что Солнце светит. - акцент не на "что", а на "светло", пауза после него является акцентом.

Comment: На "светло", думаю, акцент (смысловой) есть в обоих случаях. Я говорил о том, на какое из двух слов "потому" и "что" падает акцент внутри самого союза. насчет паузы - да, согласен.

Answer (score 1):

Если перед этой фразой был вопрос"Почему ...?", то однозначно с запятой - акцент на "потому".Каков вопрос. таков ответ. Если не было вопроса, пунктуация факультативна, как уже сказал behemothus.

Answer (score 0):

Расчленение подчинительных союзов является ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНЫМ, если подчинительный союз осложнён наречиями, частицами, вводными словами, например:   Вопросы задавали именно потому, что не всё было ясно. И горе наше произошло только оттого, что мы слишком много думали о счастье. Да и зашёл он к нему лишь потому, что случайно оказался в этом районе.